# Why virtual machine gateway ip address ends with xxx.xxx.xxx.2?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, nat, gateway

Recently, I noticed that my virtual machine gateway IP address is xxx.xxx.xxx.2 instead of xxx.xxx.xxx.1, as the gateway IP address for normal machines is xxx.xxx.xxx.1 . But that's not the case for virtual machines. My connection is in NAT with the host machine. Can anyone please explain to me why this is the case?

My virtual machine:

[image: My virtual machine]

Host Machine:

[image: Host Machine]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The two images you provided are on totally different subnets, one uses 10.x.x.x and the other uses 192.168.x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM is inside the network `10.0.2.x` while the host is in
`192.168.8.x`.

This is because the virtual machine product that you are using has created
a virtual router for all the VMs, with a DHCP server that allocates
addresses in the sub-network of `10.0.2.x`. This virtual router interfaces
to your local network via the host.

I can't answer why the developers of the virtual machine product chose
to setup the gateway as `10.0.2.2` rather than `10.0.2.1`,
except to guess that `10.0.2.1` is used for a virtual modem that interfaces
to the physical router. But that's only a guess, as the developer's choice
is not publicly documented.